# Newtonsoft throws Exception while converting string to date. Why

Tags: c#, json, string, datetime, json.net

I've got an JSON-String and convert an element of it to a c# datetime.
This works most of the time but sometimes I've got an exception:

```
Could not convert string to DateTime: 2016-11-31T18:00:00Z.
```

I fail to see why this is throwing an exception. The string looks like a correct format.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: November has only 30 days

Comment: @FlatEric Damn, you are right. I was looking over that dozends of times and missed that November has only 30 days.  Ash on my head.

Answer (score 4):

The date is invalid because November has only 30 days

For example `2016-11-30T18:00:00Z` should work because this is a valid date.